# i get this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**Any time i send a post request with the mongoose validator, this is what I get.**

> **Person validation failed: number: Path `number` (`990`) is shorter than the minimum allowed length (8). POST /api/persons 400 1974 -
> 1648.553 ms {"name":"awess","number":990}**

This error msg at top is the only error I should be getting, but I dont know why I'm getting this error below too.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
> at ServerResponse.json (/home/abdul-afeez/Desktop/Workspace/Project/FullStack-Open2021/part2/phonebook/phonebook-app-backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:257:20)
> at errorHandler (/home/abdul-afeez/Desktop/Workspace/Project/FullStack-Open2021/part2/phonebook/phonebook-app-backend/index.js:119:33)
> at Layer.handle_error (/home/abdul-afeez/Desktop/Workspace/Project/FullStack-Open2021/part2/phonebook/phonebook-app-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
> at trim_prefix (/home/abdul-afeez/Desktop/Workspace/Project/FullStack-Open2021/part2/phonebook/phonebook-app-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
> at /home/abdul-afeez/Desktop/Workspace/Project/FullStack-Open2021/part2/phonebook/phonebook-app-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
> at Function.process_params (/home/abdul-afeez/Desktop/Workspace/Project/FullStack-Open2021/part2/phonebook/phonebook-app-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
> at next (/home/abdul-afeez/Desktop/Workspace/Project/FullStack-Open2021/part2/phonebook/phonebook-app-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
> at Layer.handle_error (/home/abdul-afeez/Desktop/Workspace/Project/FullStack-Open2021/part2/phonebook/phonebook-app-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:67:12)
> at trim_prefix (/home/abdul-afeez/Desktop/Workspace/Project/FullStack-Open2021/part2/phonebook/phonebook-app-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
> at /home/abdul-afeez/Desktop/Workspace/Project/FullStack-Open2021/part2/phonebook/phonebook-app-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7*

this is my mongoose validator code and my post request with get request.

````
const mongooseUniqueValidator = require("mongoose-unique-validator");

const url = process.env.MONGODB_URI;

console.log("connecting to", url);

mongoose
  .connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then((result) => console.log("connected to MongoDB"))
  .catch((error) =>
    console.log("error connecting to mongodb :", error.message)
  );

const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, unique: true, minlength: 3, required: true },
  number: { type: String, minlength: 8, required: true },
  date: Date,
});

personSchema.plugin(mongooseUniqueValidator);

mongooseUniqueValidator.defaults.message =
  "Error, expected {PATH} to be unique.";

const Person = mongoose.model("Person", personSchema);

personSchema.set("toJSON", {
  transform: (document, returnedObj) => {
    returnedObj.id = returnedObj._id.toString();
    delete returnedObj._id;
    delete returnedObj.__v;
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Person", personSchema);

###post request

app.post("/api/persons", (request, response, next) => {
  const body = request.body;

  const person = new Person({
    name: body.name,
    number: Number(body.number),
    date: new Date(),
  });

  person
    .save()
    .then((savedPerson) => response.json(savedPerson.toJSON()))
    .catch((error) => next(error));

  // persons = persons.concat(person);
});

###get request code

app.get("/api/persons", (req, res, next) => {
  Person.find({})
    .then((persons) => res.json(persons.map((person) => person.toJSON())))
    .catch((error) => next(error.message));
});```
````

Comment: `number (990)` has a length of `3`. The validation is looking for a _minimum_ length of `8`.

Comment: yes @prasad, that gives me the first error which is Person validation failed, that is the expected error, but the second error which is typeError should not be there, and that's the challenge I'm facing

Comment: Which part of the code the error is occurring?

Comment: Did you defined your Express app instance with `const app = express()` before setting the routes?

Comment: The fourth line that started with *TypeError*

Comment: yes @Luca Pizzini